# Implement Yii2 models to consume API REST as a client

Tags: rest, api, model, yii2, client

I am developing a Yii2 application that consumes api rest as a service. I want to implement models such as Customer:: represents www.camb.com.ve/api/v1/customer and all the AR actions as verbs so I can use yii2 widgets and all functionality as it it were against a database (::findAll, ::findOne, ::find(), etc)

Comment: There are a couple of rest clients for yii2 (https://github.com/chsergey/yii2-rest-client, https://github.com/ApexWire/yii2-restclient). But I assume they are not very popular/well tested/stable.

Comment: Thanks! I will test them. I was looking for some in google and couldnt find these